# Statistics by specific users

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to extract the statistics of specific users. But something went wrong with me.

My Model

```
public function getuser($user)
    {
        $user = Client::where('user_id', $user)->where('created_at', '>=', '2022-07-01')->get();
        return $user;
    }
```

My Contoller

```
$sources = Sources::get();
```

My Blade

```
 @foreach ($sources as $item)
      <tr>
       <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->getuser(5)->count()}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->getuser(6)->count()}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->getuser(7)->count()}}</td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach
```

[i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ylho.png)

[my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srns4.png)

Comment: Please explain what is meant by something went wrong ?

Comment: Don't ask for results if you are not going to use it, let MySQL do the count for you instead (currently you are wasting memory  & time for nothing) and it's obvious you are not taking 'sources' into consideration in your query for statistics so you cannot expect to get different numbers per source.

Comment: example, please

Comment: I get the same result, for a different source